# I can't see Unity 2D GameObjects except for their orange outlines

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem in Unity where my GameObjects work fine in the Game tab, but don't show up in the scene tab. The weird thing is that I can see their orange outlines when I click them. I've tried every solution I've seen online, but they just don't want to show up. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this only happening in the Scene View or can you not see it in the Game View either?

In my below picture, you'll see I have selected the "Shaded" option. Can you make sure that's what you have as well? Because I can see the bug icon on your screen and I feel you might have changed one of these settings.
[image]